# In Solr hierarchical facets, is there a way to use another character than «/» to separate nodes in the hierarchical facetting path field?

Tags: solr, configuration, typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.1.x

I need your help.

I'm working on a Typo3 website about mathematics, and we use :

- A Solr server to provide the search engine.
- A Typo3 Solr extension to provide the connection between our Typo3 CMS and our Sorr server.

We have indexed objects that are organized in a tree, and we use this tree to provide a hierarchical facets presentation for search. For this, we generate and maintain programmatically a path string, that Solr uses.

But unfortunately we happen to have slashes «/» in some of our indexed objects titles (for example those involving fractions), and that leads to unpredicable results when rendering the hierarchical facets based on these titles, because Solr interprets the slashes as a child node.

We cannot use HTML entitizing and de-entitizing because we would loose the search features on the names, unless we manage everywhere encoding and recoding of the special characters, which we do have no time to do.

My question is simple :

Is there a way to configure a separator char for the hierarchical facets path ? For example in typoScript a neat simple configuration key :

```
plugin.tx_solr.index.fieldProcessingInstruction.separator = @@@  #<--Whatever...
```

I would be so glad to not have to dive again in the Typo3 Solr extension source code to bugfix my website !

Thanks to anybody for any clue.

Comment: Jira: how do you tokenize the path in your setup? if you are using   <tokenizer class="solr.PathHierarchyTokenizerFactory" delimiter="\" replace="/"/>, the delimiter option would help.

Comment: Negative. We do not configure any tokenizer for hierarchical facets. I tried to investigate this track but it appears to be a dead-end.

Answer (score 0):

OK, after having lost some time trying to configure it in the schema.xml and in general_schema_*.xml files, I went to the source code of the Typo3 Solr extension, my old dreaded sleeping balrog.

It appears that the separator character is specified **hardcoded** in **5 scattered class files** :

- class.tx_solr_facet_hierarchicalfacetrenderer.php
- class.tx_solr_fieldprocessor_pathtohierarchy.php
- class.tx_solr_facet_hierarchicalfacethelper.php
- class.tx_solr_fieldprocessor_pageuidtohierarchy.php
- class.tx_solr_query_filterencoder_hierarchy.php

All I did was replace it in these files (pointing to one unique public static constant, duh) and apologize to my supervisors for taking so long correcting a so simple and stupid bug, and now everything works fine !